# General Polygon Clipper: Triangulate without additional vertices

Tags: polygon, computational-geometry, triangulation, gpc

I am using GPC to break up polygons into triangles. However, GPC is very obviously creating additional vertices while generating triangles. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a different triangulator.  [poly2tri](http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Use an alternate method, such as ear clipping. This triangulates a polygon, but does not introduce additional vertices. Note, sometimes this can result in some odd triangles (very long and thin), which may be unwanted, since they are more prone to rendering artefacts.